# External IP shows me ESXi web client

Tags: vmware-esxi, ip, vmware-vsphere, web

Recently i installed Vmware ESXi on my proliant server and created some VM there , opened ports on mikrotik router and installed nginx web server and when i tried to reach it via external ip it gets me on my web client of Vsphere ESXi. Any help ? I assume that the client uses the 80 port ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have more problems than that if you're exposing your host to the world.

Comment: Get some VMWare training - it can be free if you can read.

Answer (score 3):

You're NATting to the wrong IP. Don't NAT to your host's management IP, NAT to your guest's IP.